# Unmount a Svelte component when leaving page

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have simple game built in Phaser that I load into a Svelte component (which contains leaderboard etc) as follows:

```
<script>
    import Game from '$lib/Game.svelte';
</script>


<div class="game-container">
    <Game bind:final_score />
</div>
```

However, this game seems to stay with me even when I click away from pages etc (loaded to the bottom) and will be duplicated if I return to the page. All other content on this page correctly dissapears when I click away.

How can I force this component to unmount when clicking away / no longer visible?

Comment: Probably an issue within the component, e.g. manual DOM manipulation, which one should not do. Show the code.

Comment: thanks, unfortunately I am unable to share the code of that component as its proprietary. let me deep dive on it tho and see if anythings odd